# MongoDB - Filter on First Field of a Two Field Compound Index and Sort on the Second Field?

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I am inserting **data** into my MongoDB collection of the following format.

```
{'customer_id': 1, 'timestamp': 200}
{'customer_id': 2, 'timestamp': 210}
{'customer_id': 3, 'timestamp': 300}
```

I have a **compound index** created with keys: `{ 'customer_id': 1, 'timestamp': -1 }`

```
db.collection.createIndex( { customer_id: 1, timestamp: -1 } , { name: "query for inventory" } )
```

Now, I need to *filter* such that I get the documents with `customer_id = 1` or `2` and then *sort* the documents on the `timestamp` (in descending format, that is the latest will be at the top).

My **query** looks like this:

```
db.collection.find( { 'customer_id': { '$in': [ 1, 2 ] } } ).sort( { 'timestamp': -1 } ).limit( 100 )
```

I know how to do the query but I am unsure if I should be using this Compound Index or using two Indices on the separate fields or both.

It would be really helpful if I could get a clarification on which approach to use and why that approach is better.

Comment: You are trying to sort on non-prefix subset of a compound index. See this documentation on [index, find and sort](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/#sort-and-non-prefix-subset-of-an-index).

Comment: I read the documentation but I'm still confused. my query looks like this 
`collection.find({'customer_id': {'$in': [1,2]}}).sort({'timestamp': -1}).limit(100)`

I have a index created using {'customer_id': 1, 'timestamp': -1}. According to the docs, (as far as I understood) my indexing won't be used since I am not using an equals check on my preceding index. So I'll need to change my indexing strategy to two separate indices or use {'timestamp': -1, 'customer_id': 1}. 

Can you further clarify if i'm getting things right?

Comment: Please take a look at this similar post, and this has some clarifications: [How does sorting work with `$or` and `$in` queries in MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36490738/how-does-sorting-work-with-or-and-in-queries-in-mongodb).

Comment: I suggest run `explain()` for each case and see what the query plan results are. If a sort operation uses an index you should NOT have a SORT stage in the plan (which indicates that sort is not using the index, and is performed in the memory). There are factors that affect the query performance, like number of documents in the collection and other indexes. It needs some trials and then come to conclusions based upon your observations.

Comment: Also see these related posts: [cursor sort and limit](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/#limit-results) and 
[will limit increase query speed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31162746/mongodb-will-limit-increase-query-speed/31163192#31163192).